# d3 data binding not creating child elements using join

Tags: d3.js

I am thoroughly stumped and would love a helping hand from anyone who can kick me in the right direction. I'm trying to create groups `g` and a single rectangle inside them. The `join` works great for the `g` parent but it does not create the children. What am I missing? (I'm thinking in joins!)

I've tried replacing the `join` with an `enter().append('g')` to no avail either, so I'm missing something.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78tour5z/4/).

```
var svg = d3.select("div#canvas")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", '100%')
                    .attr("height", '100%');

let NodeData = [
    {
        'x': 20,
        'y': 20,
        'id': 'abc',
        'fill': '#D4C2F1'
    },
    {
        'x': 20,
        'y': 80,
        'id': 'def',
        'fill': '#B3D2C5'
    },
];

function updateNodes(data) {

    var groups = svg.selectAll('g').data(data)
                    .join('g')
                        .attr('node-id', function (d) { return d.id; })
                        .attr('transform', function (d) { return `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})` });

    var rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
                    .data(function (d) { return d; })
                    .join('rect')
                        .attr('x', 0)
                        .attr('y', 0)
                        .attr('width', 80)
                        .attr('height', 20)
                        .attr('stroke', '#666666')
                        .attr('fill', function (d) { return d.fill; });
}

updateNodes(NodeData);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`selection.data()` requires an array (or function that returns an array). You are not passing an array to `.data()` when trying to create the child `rect`s. You are passing  an object - an individual item in the original data array, so no elements are entered.

To fix this you can simply use:

```
var rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
                .data(function (d) { return [d]; })
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzxh6rv4/),

But, this is not the best approach if you are just passing the parent's datum as is to a single child. You don't need to use a nested enter/update/exit cycle, you can just append to the parents:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll('g').data(data)
   .join('g')
   .attr('node-id', function (d) { return d.id; })
   .attr('transform', function (d) { return `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})` });

var rects = groups.append("rect")
   .attr('x', 0)
   .attr('y', 0)
   .attr('width', 80)
   .attr('height', 20)
   .attr('stroke', '#666666')
   .attr('fill', function (d) { return d.fill; });
```

Modified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hf9nwjb/)

The new child elements (`rect`s) inherit the bound data of their parents, as you can see here:

```js
var svg = d3.select("div#canvas")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", '100%')
  .attr("height", '100%');

let NodeData = [
    {
        'x': 20,
        'y': 20,
        'id': 'abc',
        'fill': '#D4C2F1'
    },
    {
        'x': 20,
        'y': 80,
        'id': 'def',
        'fill': '#B3D2C5'
    },
];

function updateNodes(data) {

  var groups = svg.selectAll('g').data(data)
     .join('g')
     .attr('node-id', function (d) { return d.id; })
     .attr('transform', function (d) { return `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})` });

  var rects = groups.append('rect')
     .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', 80)
     .attr('height', 20)
     .attr('stroke', '#666666')
     .attr('fill', function (d) { return d.fill; });
     
  rects.each(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  })
}

updateNodes(NodeData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid #D9D9D9; width: 100%; height: 600px; margin-top: 6px"></div>
```

Comment: OMG this makes so much more sense. Thank you so much for taking the time! I used your second approach and it works great. So much simpler!

Comment: Scratch that, I went back to the `[d]` option because then the `join` handles the `enter/update/exit` conditions. With just an `append` I was getting new `rects` add to each group on every update (as would be expected).

Comment: Ah yes, I should have anticipated that you'd be calling update more than once, my bad.